# How to complete this figure using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw the following picture in Puerto Rico Mathematical Olympiad. The figure is a carpet unfolding.

[image]

I couldn't do the part of the cylinder, not introduce symbols on black squares

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{latexsym}       %simbolos do Latex    
\usepackage{bbm}        %simbolos de conjuntos   
\usepackage{pstricks}   
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl, here}  
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}  
\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, angle=90]

\draw[ultra thick](0,0)--(7,0)--(7,9)--(0,9)--(0,0);    
\draw[thick] (1,0)--(1,9);    
\draw[thick] (2,0)--(2,9);    
\draw[thick] (3,0)--(3,9);   
\draw[thick] (4,0)--(4,9);   
\draw[thick] (5,0)--(5,9);
\draw[thick] (6,0)--(6,9);   
\draw[thick] (7,0)--(7,9);   
\draw[thick] (0,1)--(7,1); 
\draw[thick] (0,2)--(7,2);  
\draw[thick] (0,3)--(7,3);   
\draw[thick] (0,4)--(7,4);   
\draw[thick] (0,5)--(7,5);   
\draw[thick] (0,6)--(7,6);  
\draw[thick] (0,7)--(7,7);  
\draw[thick] (0,8)--(7,8);  
\draw[thick] (0,9)--(7,9);

\draw[thick,<-] (-0.5,0)--(-0.5,4);  
\draw[thick,->] (-0.5,4.5)--(-0.5,9);   
\draw[thick,<-] (0,-0.5)--(2.6,-0.5);  
\draw[thick,->] (3.7,-0.5)--(7,-0.5);

\draw[fill=black] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);  
\draw[fill=black] (2,1) rectangle (3,2);
\draw[fill=black] (4,1) rectangle (5,2);    
\draw[fill=black] (6,1) rectangle (7,2);
\draw[fill=black] (0,3) rectangle (1,4);   
\draw[fill=black] (2,3) rectangle (3,4);  
\draw[fill=black] (4,3) rectangle (5,4);   
\draw[fill=black] (6,3) rectangle (7,4);   
\draw[fill=black] (0,5) rectangle (1,6);    
\draw[fill=black] (2,5) rectangle (3,6);   
\draw[fill=black] (4,5) rectangle (5,6);    
\draw[fill=black] (6,5) rectangle (7,6);    
\draw[fill=black] (0,7) rectangle (1,8);    
\draw[fill=black] (2,7) rectangle (3,8);    
\draw[fill=black] (4,7) rectangle (5,8);    
\draw[fill=black] (6,7) rectangle (7,8);   
\draw[fill=black] (1,6) rectangle (2,7);    
\draw[fill=black] (3,6) rectangle (4,7);   
\draw[fill=black] (5,6) rectangle (6,7);   
\draw[fill=black] (3,0) rectangle (4,1);   
\draw[fill=black] (5,0) rectangle (6,1);   
\draw[fill=black] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);   
\draw[fill=black] (1,2) rectangle (2,3);   
\draw[fill=black] (3,2) rectangle (4,3);   
\draw[fill=black] (5,2) rectangle (6,3);   
\draw[fill=black] (1,4) rectangle (2,5);    
\draw[fill=black] (3,4) rectangle (4,5);   
\draw[fill=black] (5,4) rectangle (6,5);   
\draw[fill=black] (1,8) rectangle (2,9);   
\draw[fill=black] (3,8) rectangle (4,9);
\draw[fill=black] (5,8) rectangle (6,9);

\node at (0.5,0.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (0.5,2.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (0.5,4.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (0.5,6.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}}; 
\node at (0.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};    
\node at (1.5,1.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};    
\node at (1.5,3.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (1.5,5.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (1.5,7.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};    
\node at (2.5,0.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};    
\node at (2.5,2.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (2.5,4.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (2.5,6.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (2.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (3.5,1.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (3.5,3.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};    
\node at (3.5,5.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (3.5,7.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (4.5,0.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (4.5,2.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (4.5,4.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (4.5,6.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (4.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (5.5,1.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (5.5,3.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (5.5,5.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (5.5,7.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (6.5,0.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (6.5,2.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}}; 
\node at (6.5,4.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}}; 
\node at (6.5,6.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (6.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (6.5,1.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};   
\node at (6.5,3.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};
\node at (6.5,5.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (6.5,7.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\ostar$}}};  
\node at (1.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}};  
\node at (1.5,5.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}};  
\node at (3.5,0.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}}; 
\node at (3.5,2.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}}; 
\node at (3.5,6.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}}; 
\node at (5.5,4.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}};  
\node at (5.5,8.5) {\LARGE{\textbf{$\leftmoon$}}};   
\node at (-0.7, 4.25) {36dm};  
\node at (3.1, -0.5) {36dm}; 
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The text in black squares is black, so just add `text=white` to the node options.

Comment: Alenanno, I did. But, it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use a matrix to simplify the code.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}  
\begin{center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \def\B{\node[fill=black,text=white,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] {\LARGE$\leftmoon$};}%
  \def\W{\node[fill=white,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] {\LARGE$\ostar$};}%

\node[matrix,draw=black,ultra thick,inner sep=1pt] (grid)
{
  \W & \B & \W & \B & \W \\
  \B & \W & \B & \W & \B \\
  \W & \B & \W & \B & \W \\
  \B & \W & \B & \W & \B \\
  \W & \B & \W & \B & \W \\
  \B & \W & \B & \W & \B \\
  \W & \B & \W & \B & \W \\
  \B & \W & \B & \W & \B \\
  \W & \B & \W & \B & \W \\
};

\node[xshift=1cm,yshift=-.1cm,cylinder,rotate=90,
  draw=black,thick,fill=gray,
  minimum height=9.35cm,minimum width=2cm] at (grid.east) {};

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: demo image]

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit that my "cylinder" doesn't look very realistic, but in any case, the result can be achieved with a much shorter code. If you do not understand something, feel free to ask, but I think that typing *a lot* of `\node` definitions gets tedious.

I left your package list as it was because I don't know if you use them somewhere else in your document, but many of these are not necessary for this code.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{latexsym}       %simbolos do Latex    
\usepackage{bbm}        %simbolos de conjuntos   
\usepackage{pstricks}   
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl, here}  
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns, shadings}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \y [count=\nrow starting from 0] in {0,1,...,9} {
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,7} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\color{int(mod(\y + \x, 2)) ? "black" : "white"}
    \fill[draw,fill=\color] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\color}{white}=0
        \node[font=\bfseries\LARGE] at (\x+.5,\y+.5) {$\ostar$}; 
    \else
        \node[font=\bfseries\LARGE, text=white] at (\x+.5,\y+.5) {$\leftmoon$};
    \fi 
    }
}

\draw[left color=gray!50!black, right color=gray!50!black, middle color=gray!80, pattern color=black] (7.3,.3) --++ (0,9.7) arc (180:0:.7 and .3) -- (8.7,.3) -- cycle;
\fill[gray!30!black] (8,.25) ellipse (.7 and .3);

\draw[{Latex}-{Latex}] (0,-1) -- (8,-1)  node[fill=white, midway] {60dm};
\draw[{Latex}-{Latex}] (-1,0) -- (-1,10) node[fill=white, midway] {36dm};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alenanno, Your solution was very good. But, please, there are 5 types of symbols on the Board, see figure. I'm still with doubts about the placement of symbols in their black squares

Comment: @benedito As in, rotated moons?

Comment: Alenanno, Sorry, I don't understand. My problem is to place each symbol in the respective black house.

Comment: @benedito you said there are more symbols, so I was wondering which ones they are.

Comment: Alenanno, Thanks. The symbols to which I refer are the black houses: multiple rotations of the Moon

Comment: @benedito that shouldn't be too hard but it's night here, so I'll  check tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35587/discussion-between-benedito-and-alenanno).